# Getting #REF! error on vlookup - 3 different versions

Tags: excel, vlookup

I know of index-match but for completeness I wanted to go back to vlookup and be confident using it as well.
I'm getting #REF! errors for all 3 versions of the formula and am not sure why. I even tried to do it with the excel formula wizard by pointing and clicking but it still throws the same error.

[image]

UPDATE:

```
=VLOOKUP(B15,Dataset[ID],3,FALSE)

=VLOOKUP(B16,A2:A11,3,FALSE)

=VLOOKUP(B17,$A$2:$A$11,3,FALSE)
```

If I change the column index reference from 3 to 1, it works fine (pointing at the same value as the look up value, but it works). The moment I change it to 2 or 3 I get the Ref error.

I just created a brand new workbook and without formating the data as table, I tried it as well. The same result: if the column index value is 1 it works fine (useless but doesn't throw an error). The moment you change it to 2 or 3, it throws the Ref error. I'm puzzled. Am using the latest office version (O365) on Windows 10.

Comment: Include your formulas as plain text not as an image.

Comment: Added some more details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference multiple columns, unlike with index/match. If you want results of column C your array should be A2:C11.

Now you tell your function to look for column 3 of A2:A11, which only consists of one column.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can't believe I didn't spot it. Grrr.